# Is metalbending based on a different martial art?

Tags: the-legend-of-korra, avatar-the-last-airbender

Airbending is based on the Ba Gua Zhang martial art, Water on Tai Chi Chuan, Fire on Northern Shaolin, and Earth on Hung Ga.  Is metalbending modeled simply after Hung Ga as well or is there a different real-life martial art folded in?

Comment: In [this interview](http://www.avclub.com/articles/legend-of-korras-michael-dante-dimartino-and-joaqu,72359/), the creators mention some of the behind-the-scenes martial arts work.  I don't see anything that clearly states what *metalbending* is based on though.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not a martial arts expert, so forgive me if I misuse some terminology here.  Metalbending is based off the Chu Gar Southern Praying Mantis system.  There's an interview [here](http://www.kungfumagazine.com/ezine/article.php?article=1038) where many of the martial arts techniques behind the show are discussed:

> *So now with KORRA, will we see any new styles ? I saw a leaked clip that had metal bending.*
>
> Metal bending is an outgrowth of Toph. Actually, it's Toph's daughter who is head of the metal bending police. Toph's style was taken from my dear friend Sifu Manuel Rodriguez, of the Chu Gar Southern Praying Mantis system. ... So the metal bending police are using some of those techniques for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Metal Bending is based on the same Martial Art of Earth Bending.  That is because Metal Bending isn't really bending metal, rather it's bending the Earth within the metal.

Comment: I think the question is asking about the real life martial arts the various bending arts' movements are based off of.

Comment: It based off of the same Martial Arts of Earth Bending Hung Ga

Answer (score 1):

It depends on who you're talking about. Toph, Lin, Suyin and the metalbending police force use traditional metalbending techniques which come from earthbending. They all also use the metal wires which allow them to do this.

However, if you look at Kuvira and her metalbending army, they have a very different uniform and they changed their techniques accordingly. If you watch Kuvira taking out the bandits, you get an excellent display of how she fights, and I believe it comes from Praying Mantis Kung Fu, she then displays this again while fighting Korra. They like to wear lightweight uniforms so that they are more dexterous and they use the metal on their uniform not for big blows but for small jabs that when timed and aimed correctly can have a significant effect.